# How use Point Cloud Library (PCL) in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, dll, open-source, qt-creator, point-cloud-library

As part as a master project, I need to create a post-processing app for a 3D scan.

I discovered PCL and I managed to use it on MSVC 2015 and performed few operations with sucess without any GUI.

Now I would like to use PCL with Qt creator. 
(like in http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php).

I am a noob with Qt and I don't know how to include PCL in a project.

If anybody can help me by giving me an orientation on setting up that kind of project, or a property sheet, It'll be great,

I'm working on Windows 7 , 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

To import a libary (dll) into your Qt project, simply right-click on your Qt solution, choose "`Add libary`", then extern libary and add the libary path and the include path. This will make the header files accessable for the IDE.

Now you can code!